# AWS S3 Standard-IA minimum billable obj size pricing query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Standard - Infrequent Access Storage has a minimum billable object size of 128KB. Smaller objects may be stored but will be charged for 128KB of storage. Form https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ link

I have a 2 seperate 4KB sized files stored in S3 Standard-IA class, how are they billed? 
Do each 4kb billed for 128KB storage charge i.e, 
    4kb file billed at 128KB
Another 4KB file billed at 128KB

total 256kb of storage for billing?
Or

both combined 8KB is considered for 128KB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will be charged for 256 KB of storage.

The minimum billing object size is 128 KB. This means if you have 10 files of 1 byte each you will be billed for 10 files of 128 KB or a total of 1,280 KB for billing purposes.

Comment: Thank you @John for clarification. Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: What if you have 10 objects, 0 byte each?

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue - I am not sure about your example. However, there are no zero-byte objects when you factor in object metadata.

Comment: Right, so I am getting bunch of 0 byte keys returned: `aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://bucket.name`, e.g.: `2015-02-03 17:19:25    0 Bytes key_name`.
I am trying to understand if that's actually 0 or more bytes, and whether I am billed for 128KB or not.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue You pay for both the object size and the metadata. This means a 0-byte object would be charged at least the minimum size of 128 KB because metadata also consumes space.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley, that helps now.

Comment: What is the best cost efficient storage class where an average object size is usually less than 128 KB ? I have tera bytes of storage of this type and figuring out which would be the cost efficient